Extract basil seeds from dry husk
I have grown some basil from a conservation variety, harvested the seeds with the husks on. Removed the husks from the stem, and dried them some longer.
My question is: how do I get the seeds out of the husks? How do I do this for larger quantities (more seeds than one needs, intend to trade/barter with them).
The crumbling method is only working if I crumble the husks one-by-one, if I try to do it on more, it just does not work, the seeds stay in the husk.
Rubbing against a strainer yields similar results.
Note: the question is not about separating the empty husks (chaff) from the seeds, there are plenty of resources regarding that (winnowing, strainer method) online.

Are you sure that nature requires huskless seeds?

nature not, but if i'm trading seeds, the recipient expects huskless seeds

I've not tried to germinate my seeds yet (I did this last season), but I'm fairly confident what I have done .   If I recall, I did it in 2 stages -

I ground/grated all the seeds against a sieve into a rounded bowl to get rid of the larger parts of the outer husk using my fingers .

The part you don't care about - but I typed it before rereading your question and I'll leave it for others - I then used a combination of agitating the bowl (ie lightly tapping it) to make the lighter parts of the husk rise to the top.  I then very lightly blew on the mix at a fairly oblique angle to get rid of the lighter husk.   I did this while lightly causing the contents of the bowl to "swirl" with a gentle round shaking motion to enhance the effect.


Be prepared to either do a bad job of separating the seeds or for there to be some wastage.  (Maybe you can catch the waste and repeat.  I had vast quantities of seed for personal use, so I did not care that much - but still got a good yield)
